# Vimeo Froogaloop API, working in Fiddle but not WP

Tags: jquery, api, vimeo

I'm trying to harness Vimeo's Froogaloop API to pause video embeds whenever a user clicks a certain element. I have it working perfectly in [my Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a5gRF/) but it wont work in my Wordpress environment.

I took some code from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18485351/3216110) to create a simplified version of the site I'm working on;

**HTML**

```
<div id="player1" class="col">
    <div class="vid">
        <iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/75817361?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&api=1" width="100%" height="auto" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="player2" class="col">
    <div class="vid">
        <iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/7038107?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&api=1" width="100%" height="auto" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div>

<a class="pause" onclick="pauseAll(); return false;" href="#">Pause</a>
```

**jQuery**

```
function pauseAll() {
$('iframe[src*="vimeo.com"]').each(function () {
    $f(this).api('pause');
});
}
```

As I say, it works perfectly in my Fiddle but not in my [WP based site](http://outpost.purenine.com/our-work/) It also seems to just be Google Chrome where it doesn't work in WP which is making me scratch my head even more.

If anyone has any ideas it would be a great help.

Comment: The jQuery included with WordPress is set to [noConflict mode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers) so the `$` shortcut isn't available until you make it available. Double check that isn't the problem.

Comment: @helgatheviking I use `$` everywhere else and I don't have any problems. I've also tried replacing it with `jQuery` and the problem still persists

Answer (score 2):

From: https://developer.vimeo.com/player/js-api#universal-event-spec

> If you’re embedding and controlling multiple players on a page or
>   using our JS API library (Froogaloop), you should give each player a
>   player_id that matches the id of the iframe element.
>
> http://player.vimeo.com/video/VIDEO_ID?api=1&player_id=vimeoplayer

You may need to add the player_id query parameter to the src definition.